# How to replace values in a column if column is a list of values?

Tags: python, replace

I have a dataset that looks like this:

| ID | Language |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2945 |
| 2 | 2945, 2344 |
| 3 | NaN |
| 4 | 2945, 5657,2344 |

I want it to look like this:

| ID | Language |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | English |
| 2 | English, Arabic |
| 3 | NaN |
| 4 | English, French, Arabic |

How can I replace values if I know that:

```
({2945:'English',2344:'Arabic',5657:'French'})
```

I tried this one:

```
df['Language'].str.replace({2945:'English',2344:'Arabic',5657:'French'})
```

But it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try using `str.replace` with a lambda function:

```py
d = {2945:'English', 2344:'Arabic', 5657:'French'}
df["Language"] = df["Language"].str.replace(r'\d+', lambda m: d[int(m.group())])
```